# How to insert value in merged cell poi java

Tags: java, excel, jsf, apache-poi

i have created new row then merge two cells then i want to get this merged cell to put value in it

my code :

```
        sheet.createRow(1);
    HSSFRow row2 = sheet.getRow(1);
    HSSFCell cell = row2.getCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue("معلومات الطالب");
    sheet.addMergedRegion(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A2:B2"));
```

but i get error java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create the cell using `row2.createCell(1)` before setting the value.

Comment: How to add value to this merged area ?

Comment: Have you checked this link http://thinktibits.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/Java-POI-Merge-Cell-Data-Example-Program.html? Going through the link it looks like if you change `row2.getCell(1)` to `row2.createCell(1)`, it should work.

Comment: I have used it but it merge but it empty no data in it

Comment: You are getting empty cell because you have set the value on Cell 1 that corresponds to B2. You need to set the value on A2(Cell 0) instead as follows:    `HSSFCell cell = row2.createCell(0);` The index in the row starts from 0 not 1.

Comment: this is my code    : Row row = sheet.createRow((short) 1);
  Cell cell = row.createCell((short) 1);
  cell.setCellValue("معلومات الطالب");